# Trying to show the last message sent, collecting the info from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having issues bringing a snapshot of the last message sent to the chat's home page. It's the messaging part of my app. All the data is sent to Firebase without issue but this one part is remaining.

Here is the chatroom list:

```
    Widget chatRoomList(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatRooms,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ChatRoomTile(
                snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["chatRoomId"]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll("_", "")
              .replaceAll(Constants.myName, ""),
                snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["chatRoomId"],
                snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["message"],
            );
            /*ChatRoomTile(
              snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["chatRoomId"]
                  .toString()
                  .replaceAll("_", "")
                  .replaceAll(Constants.myName, ""),
                  snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["chatRoomId"]
            );*/
          },
        ) : Container();
      },
    );
  }
```

And here is the tile bringing in the data:

```
 class ChatRoomTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final String fName;
  final String chatRoomId;
  final String lastMessage;

  ChatRoomTile(this.fName, this.chatRoomId, this.lastMessage);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConversationScreen(chatRoomId)));
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                  child: Text(
                      "${fName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}",
                    style: largeWhiteBoldMessageTextStyle(),
                  )
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 12),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(fName, textAlign: TextAlign.start, style: mediumWhiteBoldMessageTextStyle()),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text("${lastMessage}", style: smallWhiteBoldMessageTextStyle(),),
                    Text(" . ", style: smallWhiteBoldMessageTextStyle()),
                    Text("11:27", style: smallWhiteBoldMessageTextStyle())
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The time is just static as I haven't got to it yet. I've tried moving stuff around to make it work but no luck.

Comment: Hi, Could you please post the error logs. And also would like to make sure whether you are getting the values for fname and last message

Comment: I am getting the value for fName but I believe lastMessage isn't being returned. The print(lastMessage) just prints I/flutter (26404): Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' . They are in different collections in Firebase, could that be the issue?

Comment: lastMessage returns null

Comment: you will need to debug why "snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["message"]" is returning null. Maybe try with "snapshot.data.docs[index]" and see if "message" is actually empty.